# Python: Application Must Wait Until Another Finishes (Mutex)

Tags: python, winapi, singleton, mutex

I'm creating an application that must run one at a time, so I tried to create it based on this recipe:
https://code.activestate.com/recipes/474070-creating-a-single-instance-application/

The problem is, I need the application to wait the another one finishes and then run.

I tried something like this:

```py
def __init__(self) -> None:
    while True:
        lastError = 0
        SetLastError(0)
        self.Mutex = CreateMutex(None, False, self.MUTEX_NAME)
        lastError = GetLastError()
        if (lastError != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS):
            break
        else:
            print("It's already running... Waiting...")
            time.sleep(5)

def __del__(self) -> None:
    if self.Mutex:
        CloseHandle(self.Mutex)
```

When I run this code in "debug mode" on VSCode line by line, it works, because GetLastError return 0 after the first process finishes.

But when I just run twice like `python app.py`, the second process always print "It's already running... Waiting..."

How could I solve it?

Comment: This is `win32event.CreateMutex`?

Comment: Yes, win32event.CreateMutex.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is not *owning* the created mutex in the process that created it.  Here's working code:

```py
import win32event as evt
import win32api as api

ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS = 183  # Not defined in pywin32.

class SingleInstance:
    def __init__(self):
        # Own mutex if created, handle returned in any case.
        self.Mutex = evt.CreateMutex(None, True, 'Global\\MyMutex')
        if api.GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS:
            print('Waiting for other instance')
            # Wait for the mutex to be released
            wait_result = evt.WaitForSingleObject(self.Mutex, evt.INFINITE)
            # If the other instance is closed without releasing the mutex,
            # WAIT_ABANDONED is returned.  Make sure to check for both.
            if wait_result in (evt.WAIT_OBJECT_0, evt.WAIT_ABANDONED):
                # Mutex is released, can proceed
                print('Continuing')

    def release(self):
        if self.Mutex is not None:
            evt.ReleaseMutex(self.Mutex)
            api.CloseHandle(self.Mutex)
            self.Mutex = None

    def __del__(self):  # called when instance goes out-of-scope
        self.release()

    def __enter__(self):  # called when created with "with"
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, tb):  # called when leaving "with" block
        self.release()

with SingleInstance():
    input('Application running. Press ENTER to exit:')
```

Note that owning the mutex isn't needed if the second instance simply exits (as in the ActiveState example) because in that case *creating* the mutex indicates it is the only running instance.  Since the second instance remains running the mutex must be owned so `WaitForSingleObject` can actually wait for it be released when the first instance exits.